# Use AWK to get last 2 columns of cookie files below comments

Tags: awk

I currently have a cookie.txt file that looks like so.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1547252593  GPS 1
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1552434792  PREF    f1=50000000&hl=en
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1562802793  VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE  inJgRBNv-3I
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   YSC 9U9ILYfJDyA
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   s_gl    1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==
```

I'm trying to use `awk` to read the cookie.txt file and from each of the `.youtube.com` lines get the last 2 fields, ie `GPS 1`, `PREF    f1=50000000&hl=en`, etc.

Can this be done with awk ignoring the base 3 comment lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` expression:

```
awk 'NR>4 { print $6,$7 }' cookie.txt
```

- NR>4 skips the first 4 lines
- `print $6,$7` prints the sixth and seventh field delimited by the OFS value

**Its Output is:**

```
GPS 1
PREF f1=50000000&hl=en
VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE inJgRBNv-3I
YSC 9U9ILYfJDyA
s_gl 1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==
```

Comment: Space is defauls separator, so its not need to be defined explicitely

Comment: @Romeo Ninov: Thanks. I simplified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk '$1!~"^#"  {if (NF!=0) print $(NF-1),$NF}' cookie.txt
```